# Rails + Delayed Job: Where is the correct place to store custom job classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, directory-structure

I'm new to delayed_job and i'm starting to write my own "custom jobs".  Each custom job is basically just a regular ruby class but i'm not sure where these custom job classes are normally stored within the project's directory structure.

I'm thinking lib, but lib seems to be a junk drawer at this point :/ (maybe that's ok though)

Thanks!!

Comment: I created a `delayed_jobs` folder under `/app` but it's a matter of taste :)

Comment: I have some in `lib/`, some in `app/models/`, and some that are inner classes in other classes. I only have a non-answer here: put them where it makes sense.

Comment: @apneadiving do you then simply name your classes `WhateverJob` ?

Comment: I usually name them `DelayedWhatever`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The common way for that is to create `jobs` folder under `app` folder. But the only thing you should care about is that they are your files, so do it in a way you find most comfortable for yourself.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer because it seems to be common here and it's the way i decided to go w/ my app.  Thanks!

Comment: add i forgot one thing... u can place job inside one of your model (ofc if job is directly related to that model) and use `handle_asynchronously :method_name`

Comment: thank you! I actually read that somewhere in the docs (or stack)! `handle_asynchronously :my_method` is synonymous with `delay.my_method`